# Disable File upload field in Extjs 3.0

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs3

I want to disable a file Upload field dynamically. Like I have a variable say isUploadAllowed. If this variable is true only then FileUpload field is enabled and user can click Browse button.. Else this button is disabled.. How to do it in ExtJs 3.0? I did find few examples but they were all of ExtJs 4.. I have tried:
**FileUploadField.setDisabled(true);**
but it's not working..

Here is my code, I want to disable it on reset button click!

```
var fileUploadField = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({

    id : 'fileUpload',
    name : 'upLoadedFile',
    fieldLabel : 'Supporting File(s)',
    width : 410,
    convertToUpperCase : false,
    tabIndex : 9,
    allowBlank : true

});

var requestForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            id : 'requestForm',
            labelAlign : 'right',
            labelWidth : 130,
            buttonAlign : 'right',
            frame : false,
            split : false,
            fileUpload : true,
            autoHeight : true,
            collapsible : false,
            width : 635,
            monitorValid : true,
            border : false,
            bodyStyle : 'text-align:left;padding:10 10 10 10',
            // Layout the form fields here.
            items : [{                             
                    layout : 'column',
                    border : false,
                    items : [{
                        layout : 'form',
                        bodyStyle : "text-align:left",
                        border : false,
                        items : [fileUploadField]
                            }],
                     buttons : [{
                    id : 'submitBtn',
                    text : 'Submit',
                    formBind : true,
                    handler : doSubmit,
                    type : 'submit',
                    scope : this
                    }, {
                    text : 'Reset',
                    formBind : false,
                    type : 'reset', 
                    handler : function() { 
                                              // disable file upload field
                        }
                    }]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
fileUploadField.disable();
```

sometimes it works better. Also check letter case

Comment: It's not working.. I have also tried
**Ext.getCmp('fileUpload').setDisabled(true):**
but same issue.. Even though it shows disabled: true when I debug it on my browser, but Browse button is still working and it allows file uploads..

Answer (score 0):

I made a hasty comment before which was deleted. I had the same issue with the upload functionality not being disabled, even though I disabled the field. I realized that was due to **Plupload** which was enabled on that field, so to disable the upload functionality of the uploader I disabled Plupload:

```
uploader.disableBrowse(true);
```

So check if don't have some similar plugin working as well...and disable that as well. Hope that this will help someone...it gave me some headaches.